# iptables: delete all rules by interface

Tags: iptables

Is there a way to delete all iptables rules, that relate to a given interface? I don't see any command line option for this, may be there is a shorcut bash script for this?

Comment: I could be wrong but I don't think iptables usually keeps a record of interfaces. If you're using debian/ubuntu, /etc/network/interfaces keeps a record of interfaces and IP addresses, so maybe you could whip up a script that cross-references that?

Comment: @smcg it should keep it. Try `iptables -L -v` for detailed output.

Answer (score 1):

Some possibilities, depending on your setup.

If you are running a quite simple structure of chains and dont to nesting and implications, use **iptables-save** to save your firewallset. Remove all lines with **-i $if** or **-o $if**, depending on your needs. Use grep or something. Save that ruleset, diff it to your first saved ruleset and if it's okay, load it with **iptables-restore**.

Alternatively - gather your rules in interface-specific chains. That way you can easily migrate or remove interfaces. And you are going speed up your firewall processing!

```
iptables -N fw-eth1
iptables -A FORWARD -o eth1 -j fw-eth1
iptables -A fw-eth1 --your-rules-here
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a rule to accept all the trafic on one interface : `iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -j ACCEPT ; iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -j ACCEPT`
All the trafic from or to this interface is allowed.

To delete all the firewall rules (I have a doubt in reading your text), `iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT ; iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT ; iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT ; iptables -X` : all the trafic is allowed.